# Retrieving the tag from a cell in row in a section

Tags: swift, tableview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOiux.png)I have a `tableView` with a custom `cell`. I have added a `button` to this `cell` (I have created a `UITableViewCell` subclass for this cell).

My data is distributed in 3 sections and rows. I want to be able to press the button at any row and pass that row content to the next page. I was able to do all this when I did not have any sections. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {

```
var menu = ["a", "b", "c"]


@IBOutlet weak var tblview: UITableView!


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // print(menu[section].count)
    return menu.count
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //print(menu.count)
    return menu.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddItemClassCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = menu[indexPath.row]

    cell.addBtn.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.addBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BtnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
@objc private func BtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextVC") as! NextVC
    vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
    //vc.lb.text = menu[sender.indexPath.section][sender.indexPath.row]
    vc.lb.text = menu[sender.tag]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

}

Here is the cell class:

import UIKit

class AddItemClassCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var addBtn: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

> Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'

Comment: where is `menu` array declared?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your are using a button on a cell you can use

```
import UIKit

struct Menu {
    let title: String
    let innerMenu: [String]
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var myTV: UITableView!

let menuArr = [
    Menu(title: "1", innerMenu: ["a", "b", "c"]),
    Menu(title: "2", innerMenu: ["d", "e", "f"]),
    Menu(title: "3", innerMenu: ["g", "h", "i"]),
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myTV.delegate = self
    myTV.dataSource = self
    myTV.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return menuArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuArr[section].innerMenu.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let title = UILabel()
    title.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
    title.text = menuArr[section].title
    return title
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : MyCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "MyCell") as? MyCell
    cell.lbl_Title.text = menuArr[indexPath.section].innerMenu[indexPath.row]
    cell.btn_Click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BtnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell as MyCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

@objc func BtnClicked(sender:UIButton!){
    let view = sender.superview!
    let cell = view.superview as! MyCell
    let indexPath = myTV.indexPath(for: cell)
    print("\(indexPath?.section) - \(indexPath?.row)")
}


}
```

Comment: Hi I added my code can you see?

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: so I want to make this instead:
var menu = [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e", "f"],["g", "h", "i"]]
 let headerText = ["1", "2", "3"]
And be able to pass the data when I have multiple sections too but I get this error: Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?' at this line of code: vc.lb.text = menu[sender.tag]

Comment: Hi I was trying to post my code and I was fighting a bug so I couldn't get it to work that's why I answered late lol.

Comment: let me see how i can help you. Working on your code

Comment: Thanks I am waiting

Comment: Hi @Sh_Khan can you please remove your negative comments from my post? As I said I was trying to post a correct code. and I am really trying to get an answer for my question. Please remove your duplicate and that question you are referring too. Because it is not answering my question. Thanks

Comment: @ Yogesh Tandel
 are your still trying to work on my code?

Comment: yes i need 10 mins more dear

Comment: @Sara - Didi you check

Comment: Hi Sara- did the code work for you. Do you need anything else

Comment: it looks like it is working. it prints this when I click on the buttons:Optional(0) - Optional(0) and Optional(0) - Optional(1). your code is however is very different from mine in some ways. I need to implement your ways into mine now. Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: How can I write that you answered my question?

Comment: You just mark correct on my answer

Comment: it worked great!!!! thank you so much

Comment: @Sara - you are welcome